# Refer to *ngFor element in input without (ngModel)

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an input that works as a search bar, the navigation works overall.

The problem is the "`navigate(r)`" function on my `li`, I want my "`keydown.enter = navigate(r)`" function in input to be able to access "`r`" of results and do the same as the "`(click) = navigate(r)`" function, how can I do so? Notice the `ngModel` already being used in input so I can't do two-way-binding (as far as I know).

EDIT:
"r of results" is an object with a lot of properties used later on other functions, added an image on how it works, I can navigate with arrow functions but enter isn't running the (click) function.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="search" type="text"
    [value]="emptyVal" (keyup)="searchStuff(search)"
    (keydown.ArrowDown)="goDown()"
    (keydown.ArrowUp)="goUp()"
    (keydown.enter)="navigate(r)">


<div id="results" (clickOutside)="closeSearchResults()" [hidden]="!hasResults">
    <ul (mouseover)="mouseover=true"
        (mouseout)="mouseover=false">
        <li class="item" *ngFor="let r of results$ | async; let i = index" 
        [ngClass]="{'selected': i == searchIndex && !mouseover}"
        (click)="navigate(r)" >

            <span> {{ r.name }}</span>
            <span> {{ r.level }}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

This is the html for my component and [this is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Aex.png)

Any pointing towards how to approach is very appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand. which of the many results displayed in the `<ul>` should be chosen when enter is pressed in the input?

Comment: Edited, r is a whole object to be evaluated on other functions, either the clicked or the one pressed enter on should be sent, it's supposed to work like google search input, where you can select by pressing enter or clicking a result.

Comment: If it should work like a google search, navigating up or down with the keyboard in the results should change the value of the input field. The value of the input field is bidirectionally bound to `search`. So you should be able to pass `search` to your navigate() method when enter is pressed.

Comment: I suppouse that, when you make goDown and goUp you get in a variable the index of the row selected. Use this variable (not "r") when you make the (keydown.enter) -possible in a different function that "navigate"-